# How can I push my Flask_socketio app correctly to Heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I've been trying to push my Flask_socketio app to Heroku, but Heroku can't find my app by Procfile, probably because of my package structure. How can I restructure my directory?  Or, Should I change my Procfile. Thanks in advance.

**My directory structure:**

```
|App
| |-templates
| |-main
| |-__init__.py
|app.py
|requirements.txt
|Procfile
```

**App.py:**

```
from app import create_app, socketio

app = create_app(debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

**app/**init**.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(debug=False):
    "Create an application."

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = debug
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'MRHBLR'

    from .main import main 
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    socketio.init_app(app)
    return app
```

**Procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 app:app
```

**Heroku app's log:**

```
2021-04-03T19:34:00.216344+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app'.
2021-04-03T19:34:00.217370+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-03 19:34:00 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-04-03T19:34:00.248331+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-03 19:34:00 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-04-03T19:34:00.345570+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-03 19:34:00 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-04-03T19:34:00.345660+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-03 19:34:00 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two things called `app` in your top-level, right? You have the `app.py` file and the `app` package. That is not going to work, try renaming one of them. For example, change `app.py` to `myapp.py`, then pass `myapp:app` in the Gunicorn command line.